# Verses before wrapping hand tefillin on your fingers

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, tefilin

Many Ashkenazim recite the following verses before wrapping hand tefillin on their hands:

> וּמֵחָכְמָתְךָ אֵל עֶלְיוֹן תַּאֲצִיל עָלַי, וּמִבִּינָתְךָ תְּבִינֵנִי. וּבְחַסְדְּךָ תַּגְדִּיל עָלַי, וּבִגְבוּרָתְךָ תַּצְמִית אוֹיְבַי וְקָמַי. וְשֶׁמֶן הַטּוֹב תָּרִיק עַל שִׁבְעָה קְנֵי הַמְּנוֹרָה, לְהַשְׁפִּיעַ טוּבְךָ לִבְרִיּוֹתֶיךָ. פּוֹתֵחַ אֶת יָדֶךָ וּמַשְׂבִּיעַ לְכָל חַי רָצוֹן.

The last part is from [Psalm 145:16](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26e5.htm#16), but from where does the rest come from? Who mentions this practice? Most Germans omit these verses, while I've found it in a 1712 [Polish rite siddur](https://books.google.it/books?id=HA89AAAAcAAJ&pg=PT8) from Amsterdam and it's in Artscroll as well.

Comment: There's also a minhag among some to recite "V'eirastich Li L'olam" when wrapping the tefillin around the fingers.

Comment: @ezra Those lines were written by R' Hoshea Ben Beiri

Comment: @DoubleAA Very funny way of putting the Prophet Hoshea. :) Yes, the text comes from Hoshea 2:21-22.

Comment: @ezra That's another story, and it's there in (at least) all Ashkenazic minhagim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was authored by Rabbi Moshe Elbaz - [Sefer Haichal Hakodesh](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/44544).

Sefer was published in 5413.

[Here is a link](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44544&st=&pgnum=27)

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&st=&pgnum=87

Comment: Step by step: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34915&st=&pgnum=48

Comment: I couldn't find it in the "normal" של"ה, but I could find it in the היכל הקודש. Could someone help me with the translation? (See first part of right column)
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44544&st=&pgnum=27